# Есть ли ошибка в предложении: "Да что там комната - возьми любой конспект - вот тебе и слепок."?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть ли в предложении:

> Да что там комната - возьми любой конспект - вот тебе и слепок.

пунктуационная ошибка?
Спрашиваю именно в плане не ученического текста, который будут проверять (диктанты, тесты), а как о художественном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Да что там комната: возьми любой конспект - вот тебе и слепок". Желательно использовать двоеточие, так как два тире делают неясной структуру предложения (можно подумать, что идет обособление центральной части). Двоеточие здесь будет классическим: подчеркнутая пауза, далее разъяснение первой части.

Правда, смысл высказывания, если судить только по этому предложению,  не очень понятен.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно

Answer (score 0):

Не хочется согласиться с [@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F). По-моему, больше подходит вопросительный или - в зависимости от экспрессии - даже вкупе с восклицательным знаком. "Да что там комната?!" и т. д. Конечно, двоеточие лучше, чем тире, но оно несёт непонятную смысловую нагрузку. Только паузу? А затем разъяснение первой части? Все три части почти не связаны друг с другом по смыслу, если его не притягивать за уши. "Правда, смысл высказывания, если судить только по этому предложению, не очень понятен", - отмечает и сама автор ответа. Впрочем, я не настаиваю на своей интерпретации. Это всего лишь мнение любителя, интуиция которого часто подводила его под монастырь (а что значит - " подвести под монастырь?)"

Comment: Нет, первая часть предложения - это не вопрос и не восклицание, @София правильно поняла смысл предложения